# What unit is the Shape_Length field in for the GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS projection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

How can I convert these to values to meters? I'm trying to use the Densify tool but can't because I'm assuming the distance field is tied to Shape_Length.

Comment: There's a great deal missing here:  What geodata storage format are you using?  Is there an actual "Shape_Length" field in the table?  If so, how was it populated?  The Densify tool uses the units in which the data is stored (Cartesian degrees for GCS coordinate references).  You can't reliably convert Cartesian degrees to meters over any significant distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are working in a Geographic Coordinate System based upon the North American Datum of 1983.
The unit of measurement will be in degrees.
It will probably be necessary to transform the data into a state plane coordinate system that fits in the area of interest.
Pick a NAD 1983 State Plane Meters Zone that will work for you, then you should be able to do what you desire.

Comment: The only issue is I'm trying to develop a method that can be used with a variety of different files and I was hoping to not have to change the projection for individual files

Comment: You could just throw a 'reproject' function into your model to reproject all input data sets to a projected coordinate system so that you can properly work with distances.

Comment: @ThomasHorner, you can make shape queries in any projection you want by specifying a spatial reference. A few tools support this such as cursors and [add geometry attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm).

Comment: @Paul, wooaahh, is that new?  Looks like as of 10.2....  I only have extensive modelbuilder experience in 9.3 and 10.0.  That's a really cool, and really useful new feature.